# log4net array of elements in configuration appender

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

How can I write something like this:

```
<appender name="MyAppender" type="MyNamespace.MyAppender, MyDll">
    <url value="http://example1.com" />
    <url value="http://example2.com" />
    <url value="http://example3.com" />
</appender>
```

in log4net Appender configuration file, and have it deserialized to my custom property in my class:

```
public class MyAppender : BulkAppender
{
    public string[] Url { get; set; }
}
```

I don't have any problems with single string, but whatever I do, I cannot deserialize an array.

Comment: Maybe wrap them into anoter element (`<urls><url .../><url ... /></urls>`) and rename your property as `public string[] Urls`?

Comment: @Evk Doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not most elegant solution, but you can use list instead of array:

```
public class MyAppender : BulkAppender
{
    public List<string> Url { get; set; }
}
```

And then use something like this in your app.config:

```
<url>
  <add value="http://example1.com" />
  <add value="http://example2.com" />
  <add value="http://example3.com" />
</url>
```